# how to fix not in for two fields error?

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT   Tbl_EmpAttendance.Emp_No,Att_Date, Att_Kind, Decription, a_name, Job_Name,
            DepName, SecName, BranchName, DegName, S_Time, E_Time,S_Time1, E_Time1,Notes,
            case when Att_Kind =3 or Att_Kind = 4 or Att_Kind = 5 then (case when (datediff(minute,Convert(varchar(8),Work_E_Time,8) ,convert(varchar(8),isnull(E_Time,Work_E_Time),8)) < 0) then (datediff(minute,Convert(varchar(8),Work_E_Time,8),convert(varchar(8),isnull(E_Time,Work_E_Time),8))) * -1 else 0 end ) else 0 end  Early_Time,
            case when Att_Kind = 2 or Att_Kind = 6 or Att_Kind = 4 then (case when (datediff(minute,Convert(varchar(8),Work_S_Time,8),convert(varchar(8),isnull(S_Time,Work_S_Time),8)) > 0) then (datediff(minute,Convert(varchar(8),Work_S_Time,8),convert(varchar(8),isnull(S_Time,Work_S_Time),8))) else 0 end) else 0 end   Late_Time
into #t1
            FROM Tbl_EmpAttendance INNER JOIN
                      TblCalendar_WorkingHours ON Tbl_EmpAttendance.Att_Date = TblCalendar_WorkingHours.Calendar_Date
                      INNER JOIN dbo.tblEmp_Situation ON tblEmp_Situation.Emp_No=Tbl_EmpAttendance.Emp_No
                    AND  tblEmp_Situation.Attendance_Code = TblCalendar_WorkingHours.AttendanceType_Code
                    AND tblEmp_Situation.Trans_Date = (SELECT MAX(S.Trans_Date) FROM tblEmp_Situation S WHERE S.Emp_No =tblEmp_Situation.Emp_No )   Where (att_kind =2 or att_kind =4 or att_kind =6)  Or (att_kind =3 or att_kind =4 or att_kind =5)  Or (att_kind =5 or att_kind =7 or att_kind =12)  Or (att_kind =6 or att_kind =8 or att_kind =11)  Or (att_kind =10)  And WorkingType_Code = 1   ORDER BY Emp_No asc ,Att_Date desc


--********************* Start Of Error *****************************************
select * from #t1 where emp_no AND Att_Date  not in( select emp_no ,AttDate from AttendanceNotices)
--********************* End  ***************************************************



drop table #t1
```

Comment: The description is a mess! Unreadable... Please format your code...

Comment: You **can't** do `x IN (a, b)`, it's not possible. The subquery must return 1 column and 1 column only. To solve this do a JOIN instead.

Comment: Man,i was thinking to edit this but don't know from where to start

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is just a dump of unreadable SQL

Answer (score 0):

Your select statement in the NOT IN cannot include two fields.

Also seems you have syntax error here:

```
AND tblEmp_Situation.Trans_Date = (SELECT MAX(S.Trans_Date) FROM tblEmp_Situation S WHERE S.Emp_No =tblEmp_Situation.Emp_No )   Where (att_kind =2 or att_kind =4 or att_kind =6)
```

The second `WHERE` is not necessary, it should be either `OR` or `AND` depending on your logic

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do an `x IN (select a, b ...`, the IN value list must contain 1 column.

You cannot do `x and y in (select a, b ...` as the IN value list must still contain 1 column.

Instead, you would do a `JOIN` for `IN` and `NOT EXISTS` for `NOT IN`:

```
select
    *
from
    #t1
where
    not exists (
        select
            *
        from
            AttendanceNotices as AN
        where
            #t1.emp_no = AN.emp_no
        and #t1.Att_Date = AN.AttDate
    )
```